# Trouble integrating EMR with S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, emr, amazon-iam

I am having trouble integrating EMR with S3 i.e to implement EMRFS

EMR Version: emr-5.4.0

When I run `hdfs dfs -ls s3://pathto/bucket/` I get following error

> ls: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: XXXX), 
>   S3 Extended Request ID: XXXXX**

Please guide what is that, what I am missing ?

I have done following steps

1. Created a KMS Key for EMR
2. Added EMR_EC2_DefaultRole as key users in newly creates KMS Key
3. Created a S3 Server Side Encryption Security Config policy for EMR
4. Created new Inline policy for role/EMR_EC2_DefaultRole and EMR_DefaultRole for S3 bucket access
5. Created a EMR cluster manually with new EMR Security policy and following configuration classification

   ```
   "fs.s3.enableServerSideEncryption": "true",
   "fs.s3.serverSideEncryption.kms.keyId":"KEYID"
   ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EMR, by default,  will use instance profile credentials(*EMR_EC2_DefaultRole*) to access your S3 bucket. The error means this role does not have necessary permissions to access S3 bucket.

You will need to verify the **IAM Role policy** of that role to allow necessary S3 actions on both bucket and objects (Like s3:list*). Also check if you have any explicit Deny's etc. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html

The access could also be denied because of a **Bucket policy** on set on the S3 bucket you are trying to access. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/iam-policies-and-bucket-policies-and-acls-oh-my-controlling-access-to-s3-resources/

Your EMR cluster could be using an [VPC endpoint for S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints-s3.html) to access S3 rather than Internet/NAT. In that case, you'll also need to verify **VPC endpoint policies** as well. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints-s3.html#vpc-endpoints-policies-s3